# Unit test for checking automapper mappings

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

I using automapper and want to write unit test to check if mapping working correctly

Here is my automapper profile

```
  public class MappingsProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingsProfile()
    {
        #region CompaniesHouse

        CreateMap<CompanyHouseDto, InputCompaniesHouseSearchResult>().ReverseMap();

        CreateMap<IntegrationCompaniesHouseStateDto, IntegrationCompaniesHouseState>();

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is Test that I already wrote

```
 public class AutomapperTest
{
    private static IMapper _mapper;

    public AutomapperTest()
    {
        if (_mapper == null)
        {
            var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new MappingsProfile());
            });
            IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Map_Should_HaveValidConfig() => _mapper.IsValid();

    [Fact]
    public void Map_Should_MapEntityToDto()
    {
        var entity = new InputCompaniesHouseSearchResult();
        var dto = _mapper.Map<CompanyHouseDto>(entity);

        Assert.NotNull(dto);
        Assert.IsType<CompanyHouseDto>(dto);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Map_Should_MapDtoToEntity()
    {
        var dto = new CompanyHouseDto();
        var entity = _mapper.Map<InputCompaniesHouseSearchResult>(dto);

        Assert.NotNull(dto);
        Assert.IsType<InputCompaniesHouseSearchResult>(entity);
    }
}
```

Here is DTO

```
    public class CompanyHouseDto
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    
    public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }
    
    public string CompanyStatus { get; set; }
    
    public string CompanyType { get; set; }
    
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    
    public string CompanyProfileLink { get; set; }
    
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    
    public string Country { get; set; }
    
    public string Locality { get; set; }
    
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    
    public string Region { get; set; }
    
    public string SicCodes { get; set; }
    
    public string MatchConfidenceBand { get; set; }
    
    public int MatchConfidenceScore { get; set; }
}
```

`InputCompaniesHouseSearchResult` has same fields.

If I change  AddressLine1 to AddressLineABC all tests will pass, I need test to fail on this  .

How I need to write tests?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html

Comment: Did you find a solution for this test using Automapper?